# Открытие двух зависимых файлов

Tags: excel

На производстве есть два файла Excel.
Один из них представляет собой огромный справочник – почти не изменяется и находится на одном из сетевых дисков.
Второй файл – изменяемые проектные данные, в котором находятся множественные LOOKUP ссылки на первый файл.

Второй файл открывается и работает отлично, но только когда первый файл был до этого открыт. Проблемы и тормоза возникают, когда первй файл закрыт.

Как добиться того, что бы первый файл открывался автоматчески, когда отрыватеся второй? 
Пробовал открывать первый файл в событии  Workbook_Open() второго, но эффект тот же: все грузиться очень долго. Похоже Excel анализирует спева все  LOOKUP ссылки, а уже затем вызывает Workbook_Open(). Даже тогда, когда вычисление формул установленно на вручную.

Можно это сделать средствами Excel? Есть ли другие способы что бы улучшить скорость открытия второго файла?

Comment: Иметь третий файл, из которого открыть сначала первый файл, потом второй. А вообще - пора уходить от формул и данные обрабатывать в массивах.

Comment: А можно как-то из системы файл отрыть? Я пробовал в BAT-файле, через команды START. Но как тогда дождаться отрытия первого файла полностью, прежде чем отрывать второй?

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, что с проблемой я справился. В настроках ссылок, указал, что при открытии файла ссылки не должны обновляться. Теперь второй файл открывается очень быстро. Для того что бы ссылки заработали нужно открыть первый файл, например в событии  Workbook_Open.